# Android encoding support different between phones

Tags: android, encoding

I have a problem when encoding in Android

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream().write("ĐŠŽĆČđšžćč".getBytes("CP852"));
```

Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ has no problem when this encoding CP852(or any other for that matter) while for example Samsung Galaxy S4 throws Unsupported Encoding Exception for CP852, CP858, CP857 and similar, but CP1250, CP1251 and so on work correctly.

Is there any way to go around this issue, a library? CP852 is required supported encoding.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For anyone interested: I have managed to solve the problem across all devices using JCharset library by extending it with missing charsets, contact me if you need any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use extra code to transcode unicode data to cp852. You may use some library or even do it by yourself. It shouldn't be very hard. [Here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP852.TXT) you can find cp852 to unicode mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this is only one of encodings used among about 40 others in the application, but encodings in 800 range do not seem to work on this specific phone and I'm not sure if it's android problem or some other. I'm not sure if specifically transcoding for CP852 would solve the problem, because the same Unsupported Encoding Exception arises when using CP858 CP857 and so on.

Comment: @IgorBenić I guess it is a vendor decision - to include some charsets / codepages or not. So to be sure that your app will work everywhere you should use your own encoders for all encoding you are interested in.